# Scala reflection type equality of generic wildcard

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm trying to test equality between a vector of generic types and a list of input parameters to a case class constructor. I've figured out how to use reflection to get the list of parameter and their types, but I can't figure out how to test for equality between the object instances and those types, when the object instance is a generic.

Here is a simplified example:

```
abstract class Foo[T]
case class Bar[T](value: Seq[T]) extends Foo[Seq[T]]

def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = typeTag[T]

// In my use case I have a function that can return any 
// Foo, which is why I've used the wildcarded generic here
val bar: Foo[_] = Bar[Int](Seq(2))

// In my use case I actually get the type for a parameter list
// of a case class constructor, but putting this here for simplicity
val bar2 = Bar(Seq(1))
var barType = getType(bar2)
```

I want to be able to test that bar is of type barType, but this is as close as I can get. I'm not sure how to get the type signature with the specified generic value.

```
scala>runtimeMirror(barClass.getClassLoader).classSymbol(barClass).toType
res112: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Bar[T]

scala> getType(bar2)
res113: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Bar[Int]
```

I'm pretty new to Scala (and JVM reflection in general), so thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

You can create traits as parent for all the types you wish to use and then using pattern matching for type to get the correct object type at runtime. Scala has a very powerful pattern matching functionality.

This link might be useful: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala